# How do I run small python scripts in a html website without using frameworks like flask, and django?

Tags: python, html, pytube

I have 10 line python code and a third party python library that I want to use in a html website. I do not want to use a full fledged framework like django to complete the task. I want to use the following library https://github.com/nficano/pytube in my project.  Thank You looking forward for some assistance.

Comment: http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/

Answer (score 0):

The most simple thing come to my mind is following.

1) You'll need to use some sort of WSGI (https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, for example), to serve your script as a web service.

2) You'll also need a little bit of JavaScript code to make AJAX (for example) requests to that script.